# How to download CSV in ASP.Net VB - Used to work Has stopped working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, download

I'm trying this.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFile)
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

where `strFile` is `AllSites_21Aug2014_145914.csv`

on a web page called `MicadDataCSV.aspx?SessID=1`

but what is offered to download is `MicadDataCSV_aspx?SessID=1`

NB this worked a week or two ago and has stopped working now.

Comment: You'll have to figure out what is different now and then. If the code didn't change, then the problem might not be there. Check IIS settings, check the difference in filename, check the version of the browser, windows update.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any explanation of why this was happening, but in the end just tried the fingers crossed hope this works re boot, which thankfully it did.
I still don't know what caused this problem, let alone preventing it happening again, so not good, but enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Server.HtmlEncode(strFile))
```

Comment: Tried suggestion above, but it is still the webpage file name which is offered for download rather than the csv file.

Comment: I've also tried running this code on other machines and it works fine, which makes me think its an environmental problem.

Comment: I've checked the MIME types in IIS and that doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird.  I can't think of why this would be happening.  Sorry I'm not being more help.  I'll research a bit more.

Comment: That's really kind of you. I think I'm going to be pulling my hair out in frustration :-)